# Improve query to calculate number of rows matching 20 minute window for every row

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE windowPeriod (IN BEGIN_TIME DATETIME)
BEGIN
DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE minuteCount INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE END_TIME DATETIME;
DECLARE eachMinute CURSOR FOR 
    select  count(*) as C
        from  
        (
            SELECT  *
                from  DATA timestamp >= BEGIN_TIME
                  and  timestamp <= 
                    ( SELECT  addtime(BEGIN_TIME, "00:20:00") )
                group by  user,host,timestamp
        ) as X;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
OPEN eachMinute;
addMinute: LOOP
   FETCH eachMinute INTO minuteCount;
   IF finished = 1 THEN 
      LEAVE addMinute;
   END IF;
select CONCAT (BEGIN_TIME," ", minuteCount);
END LOOP addMinute;
CLOSE eachMinute;
```

I have a table DATA that contains several entries for a minute. For each row in the table, i want to calculate "how many rows within a 20 minute period starting that minute"? I write the above query, but this gets tremendously slow as the number of rows increases. Whats a better way to achieve this?

Sample entries in the table :

```
2022-09-10 23:22:05 Linux1
2022-09-10 23:22:05 Linux2
2022-09-10 23:26:04 Linux3
2022-09-10 23:26:04 Linux4
2022-09-10 23:33:04 Linux5
2022-09-10 23:33:04 Linux5
2022-09-10 23:35:04 Linux7

2022-09-10 23:48:04 Linux7
2022-09-10 23:52:05 Linux1
2022-09-10 23:55:05 Linux2
2022-09-10 23:56:04 Linux3
2022-09-10 23:57:04 Linux4
```

So if 23:22:05 is the first minute of the window, then there are 2 rows that are within the 20 minute window (Linux1 and Linux3 rows). If 23:35:04 is the first minute of the window, then there is just 1 row in the 20 minute window (Linux3 only).

Comment: your query has a bug and must produce an error, and please provide a [mre] this really doesn't look like it needs a loop at all

Comment: Baffled by this your cursor group by user,host,timestamp , timestamp could hh:mm:ss but you aren't grouping by minute and adding 20 minutes could flip into a new hour. with a lower minute value than you started with. Additionally why would you group by user,host and then ignore them in loop?

Comment: @nbk - Curious to know why this wouldn't need a loop.

Comment: @P.Salmon - i didn't quite understand how flipping into a new hour could result in a lower minute value. Also, i didnt understand "i am not grouping by minute" or ignore "grouping by user,host" in loop? Sorry am an amateur at this.

Comment: your data has no multiple entries per minute, and should also contains data for more than 20 minutes. Without seeing the data as they are and what result you expect from that data,, we will not be able tio help you. LOOP's are costly and should be avoided, if possible.

Comment: @nbk i have updated the query with some more data. If 23:22:05 is the starting minute of the 20 min window, then there are 7 entries. If 23:26:04 is the starting one, then there are 5, for 23:33:04, there are 5 entries in the 20 min window (3 23:33 ones, 1 23:48 and 1 23:52 one)

Comment: Start by getting rid of a select and imply using an expression:  `timestamp < BEGIN_TIME + INTERVAL 20 MINUTE`

Comment: @RickJames Sure. I have changed it to DECLARE eachMinute CURSOR FOR select count(*) as C from (select * from CTC_NEW_LICENSE_DATA where os=OSName and timestamp >= BEGIN_TIME and timestamp <= (BEGIN_TIME + INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) group by user,host,timestamp) as X;

Comment: And use < instead of <-.

Answer (score 0):

SQL likes things to be done en masse, not in loops.

This does most of the work, and does it for the entire table, without looping:

```
SELECT  FLOOR(TO_SECONDS(begin_time) / (20*60)) AS chunk
        COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY chunk;
```

The idea is to convert the time to a number, then convert that to integers...  0 for the first 20 minutes, 1 for the next 20, etc.  That way, all items in the first 20 minutes will be lumped together and counted.

Since you may want the 'start' of each chunk showing:

```
SELECT  FROM_SECONDS(chunk * 20*60) AS start_at.
        ct
    FROM ((the above query)) AS x
    ORDER BY start_at;
```

It gets messier if you need to show "0" for intervals with no action.

Comment: I am afraid i haven't quite understood this seemingly elegant solution. Can you explain it please? select TO_SECONDS (chunk * 20*60) AS start_at,ct from (select FLOOR (TO_SECONDS('2022-09-16 19:14:00')/(20*60)) AS chunk,COUNT(*) as ct from DATA group by chunk) AS X order by start_at;
+----------+-------+
| start_at | ct    |
+----------+-------+
|     NULL | 92226 |
+----------+-------+ I ran the above and it doesnt seem to show what i'd expect.

Comment: select timestamp from DATA where timestamp>='2022-09-16 19:14:00' and (timestamp <= '2022-09-16 19:14:00' + INTERVAL 20 MINUTE); shows 559 rows - and that's what am hoping to see.

Comment: I added some prose.  I'm using a fairly standard computer science technique.